# in Finite Element, which approximation requires less number of unknowns: B-splines vs Shape functions vs Spectral Elements

Tags: finite-element, approximation, spectral-method, b-spline

In Finite Element Analysis, one requires to approximate the solution in terms of basis functions. My questions is, which method in general is better? by 'better', I mean which involves less number of unknowns to yield a certain accuracy? Let the solution of the problem be continuous and smooth in the domain of interest. I know this depends on the function which is to be approximated, But in general one of the methods should be superior. My guess is that B-splines require less number of unknowns because they do not require the all higher derivatives of the approximation be continuous as opposed to spectral elements. See e.g.

[https://web.njit.edu/~vb82/Teaching/SPRING2016/MATH340Lab/Lab7/html/Lab7Solution_withfuncs.html](https://web.njit.edu/%7Evb82/Teaching/SPRING2016/MATH340Lab/Lab7/html/Lab7Solution_withfuncs.html)

Comment: The least number of unknowns is for constant elements (one per element), which is essentially finite volumes or discontinuous galerkin. However the asymptotic convergence of those is not very good. Higher order polynomials have more degrees of freedom (e.g. in 2D: 1, 3, 6, 10, 15) and thus result in more unknowns, but at the same time they offer better convergence as the size of the elements decreases. So there is no "best", it depends on your setting.

Comment: @lightxbulb I mean, the total number of unknowns in the whole domain, not the number of unknowns per element.

Comment: The two are related.

Comment: @lightxbulb I "feel" that basis functions of degree $N$ with discontinuous derivatives have better approximation profile compared to those with all its derivatives continuous. Is that correct?

Comment: @lightxbulb Could you elaborate about your claim: "one DOF  per element using discontinuous Galerkin method". This is definitively not the case with higher order polynomials.

Comment: Just counting DoFs is not a useful metric. If that's your goal, use a global Fourier basis. What matters more is how long it actually takes you to *compute* something with the basis you choose.

Comment: @ConvexHull I am specifically refering to constant elements there, I mention FVM and DG because at least I don't know of a way to make those work with continuous Galerkin. As far as higher order DG elements go, the Lagrange ones scale the same, the difference is that you get globally less dofs in CG since some nodes are shared (you can compute an upper bound e.g. for a triangulation).

Comment: @HoseinJavanmardi I don't know what you mean by "better approximation profile". However if I were to take linear elements, on the same triangular mesh, and in one case I require a continuous solution, and in the other I allow discontinuities (i.e. vertices are not shared), then clearly the discontinuous space is richer, but it also has more degrees of freedom. Generally more degrees of freedom means more expensive matrix-vector multiplies due to a larger matrix bandwidth, but it also typically means faster asymptotic convergence to the solution with decreasing element size.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth other metric of computational complexity is the matrix sparsity?

Comment: @HoseinJavanmardi Choosing basis functions that aren't (as) almost-orthogonal (e.g. for higher order continuity) would make a tangent matrix more dense, which increases the computational effort to solve the system even if the the number of unknowns are unchanged. This is just to say that your definition of "better/superior" by just counting DOFs isn't typically what anyone else would care about, but rather how long it takes to solve.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman If it is integral equation, the matrix is inevitably fully dense.

Comment: @HoseinJavanmardi I don't understand what you are trying to claim here. Density of a tangent matrix depends only on the level orthogonality of the chosen of basis functions.

Comment: For a steady-state linear problem that discretizes to a system $Ax=b$, solving a $1{,}000\times1{,}000$ dense system will take far more time than even a $10{,}000\times10{,}000$ system that is very sparse. This is because the typical algorithms for solving these systems in PDE applications rely only on computing the matrix-vector products $Av$ instead of constructing $A^{-1}$ directly, so the biggest bottleneck is how fast you can compute $Av$, which is faster if $A$ is sparse.

Comment: @whpowell96 You mentioned a key matter of discussion. Choosing between solving differential or integral equations or even a hybrid one is a difficult decision. According to references, I have come to this conclusion that if the matrix size is small enough, integral equation is better than PDE solving using FEM. However, as you mentioned the latter leads to sparse matrix and may be even more computationally efficient. Right now I decide to use integral equation (BEM if possible), but I am not sure if it is better than PDE/FEM.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments below your post you may reach the conclusion that # DOFs and speed have no correlation whatsoever - this is not true. Keeping all other things fixed and increasing the number of unknowns it is clear that you would need to access more memory and perform more arithmetic operations. You don't need to trust me on that - you can test linear vs quadratic triangular elements where you have fixed the number of elements to be the same. The latter results in a slightly denser matrix and has more unknowns (# of vertices + # of edges versus just # of vertices for linear).

However the reason for choosing higher order polynomials is to get a better decrease rate of the error with the decrease of the size of the elements, so the goal for choosing higher order elements is slightly different. A fairer comparison there would be to compare linear elements on a mesh with $n$ vertices vs quadratic element on a mesh where the number of vertices plus edges sums up to $n$. Then you would expect the latter to get closer to the true solution as you decrease the element size.

In FEM if you have $m$ Dirichlet nodes and $(n-m)$ independent nodes, you get $n-m$ unknowns, and a (sparse) matrix that is $(n-m)\times (n-m)$. While you can grow the number of unknowns in order to get a better approximation, this generally also makes the solving process slower. If $m\ll n$ then you may opt to use Green's functions for the solution instead, which result in systems of size $m\times m$. These systems are typically dense, but as long as $m$ is small enough you can use a direct solver on those. The main practical issue there is whether you can construct the Green's functions efficiently. For example one can do so for the Poisson equation on a rectangular domain with a regular grid and with zero Dirichlet, reflecting, or periodic boundary conditions at the rectangle's boundaries, by using respectively the discrete sine, cosine, or Fourier transform (then the resulting solution strategy is typically termed fast Poisson solver. In the general case one has to compute columns of the generalised inverse of the non-reduced FDM/FEM/FVM matrix in order to get the Green's functions, so this can be more expensive than just running an iterative solver on the sparse formulation.

Discretisations based on the Green's function formulation are typically termed BEM or RBF based solutions in case you want to look those up. Typically a closed form solution for the Green's functions is not known for arbitrary meshings over arbitrary geometry however.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge. I understand that the number of unknowns is not the only measure of computational complexity. I am also aware of the benefits of sparse matrix (which is not the case of integral equation methods as you already mentioned). But If one is not able to make the matrix sparse, then the only choice to reduce computational time is to reduce the number of unknowns, Is that correct?

Comment: @HoseinJavanmardi Beyond chaging the hardware or the solver yes, your problem scales in terms of the numbers of unknowns. In fact often as the matrix grows the condition number also grows, so iterative solvers becomes slower to converge. You can of course try to port your code to the GPU or use better solvers (e.g. multigrid, preconditioners, etc).

Comment: I am scheduling to use BEM for 2-d potential problems. According to my reference articles, it is a promising work compared to FEM on PDE. That is why I need to use the  basis functions which requires the least number of unknowns for a given accuracy. Thus far I doubt whether to use spectral elements or B-splines or the classic hat(tent) functions. Can you edit your answer based on my requirements?

Comment: @HoseinJavanmardi You should probably make a separate question with all of the details concerning your problem: the PDE you're trying to solve, the discretisation of said problem, the hardware you plan to use (CPU or GPU), otherwise it's way too vague for anyone to say anything with certainty. What I can say about BEM, is that provided you know a fast way to compute the Green's functions, then you can take the best discretisation you can think of, since your matrix will be dense anyways. Also note that this is faster or even feasible only for a small enough number of Dirichlet nodes.